# Select a value from an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

From an array of hashes:

```
response = [
  {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955},
  {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"rex", "id" => 550081}
]
```

is there a way to write something like:

```
response.name.kitty
```

to retrieve the hash that contains this value:

```
{"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}
```

Comment: There is a way to do almost anything dynamically in Ruby by overriding method_missing. What is the purpose of your idea?

Comment: @dcorking: confuse the hell out of coworkers, perhaps? :)

Comment: My thinking was that there may be a way in ruby via Meta Programming using Strut or OpenStrut that will allow you to select a value dynamically from a array of hashes or array of deeply nested hashes.  Maybe I need to convert it to json and then use instance methods.  Sorry if I am not explaining what I am trying to achieve clearly

Comment: Please explain why Amit's answers don't do what you need. That might help us better understand your question.

Comment: Amit's answer is great, what I was looking for there may be a way in ruby to select a value in a array of hashes dynamically.

Comment: What extra dynamic feature do you need to add to Amit's answers?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this -

```
response.select{|x| x["name"] == "kitty"}.first
```

Comment: Which gives you the following result: ```{"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}```. Example: https://repl.it/BATV

Comment: Or just use detect/find instead of select+first

Comment: @SergioTulentsev......yes, we can do this >>>  `response.find{|x| x["name"] == "kitty"}`

Answer (score 4):

if you're using Rails - just use `.pluck`

```
array_of_hashes = [
  { name: "Kate", city: "Minsk", country: "Belarus", id: 1 },
  { name: "Mike", city: "New York", country: "USA", id: 2 },
  { name: "Aleh", city: "Warsaw", country: "Poland", id: 3},
]


>> array_of_hashes.pluck(:name)
>>
>> [ "Kate", "Mike", "Aleh" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a Proc

```
response = [{"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955},
            {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"rex", "id" => 550081}]
finder = Proc.new {|k, v| response.find {|r| r[k] == v} }
```

Then

```
finder.call('name', 'rex')
# => {"label"=>"dog", "name"=>"rex", "id"=>550081} 
finder.call('label', 'cat')
# => {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}
```

Comment: I like this way `Proc` 1+ for this

Comment: Or `finder['name', 'rex']`

Comment: With some tweaking the proc could accept a hash, i.e. `finder['label' => 'cat', 'name' => 'sam']`

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass multiple conditions if required like this:

```
response = [
  {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955},
  {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189956},
  {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189957},
  {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"meow", "id"=>189957},
  {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"rex", "id" => 550081},
  {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"tommy", "id" => 550082},
  {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"rex", "id" => 550083}
]

> response.select{|h| h["label"] == "cat" && h["name"] == "kitty" && h["id"] == 189955}
=> [{"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}] # returns array of selected hashes

> response.find{|h| h["label"] == "cat" && h["name"] == "kitty" && h["id"] == 189955}
=> {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955} # returns first match element
```

Comment: `select` + `first` finds all elements and throws away all but the first. Use `find` instead, it stops after the first match.